# C binary file reading

Tags: c

I have a little problem with reading a binary file, while the last record is readed twice.
I entered 4 records, but 5 records are printed with always the last record printed twice.

```
int main ()
{
   FILE *fp;
   fp = fopen( "file" , "a+" );

   struct clientsData {int num1; int num2; char str[20]; };

   if (getchar()=='w')
   {
        int n1,n2;
        char name[20];
        scanf("%d",&n1);
        scanf("%d",&n2);
        scanf("%s",name);

       struct clientsData client;
       client.num1=n1;
       client.num2=n2;
       strncpy(client.str,name, 20);


       fwrite(&client , 1, sizeof(struct clientsData) , fp );
    }
    else
    {

        while (!feof(fp))
        {
            struct clientsData client;
            fread(&client, 1, sizeof(struct clientsData) , fp);
            printf("%d\t%d\t%s\n",client.num1, client.num2, client.str);
        }
    }
    fclose(fp);

    return(0);
}
```

Output:

```
1   1   asd
2   3   asd
23  90  player
23  23  marin
23  23  marin
```

Comment: As i understood the c when find eof character then go for the loop for one more time. or am i wrong?

Comment: There are problems with how code reads `name` and `strncpy(client.str,name, 20);` as neither insures the result has `'\0'` termination.  Use `scanf("%19s",name);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem arises from the way `feof` works. It returns true if you have exceeded the limit of the file (if you attempted to read something after the last character). So, the way your program currently works is: read the last valid data and print it, try to read again data (fread fails, the content of your data structure is the same, print it (you get the same output), feof returns now true, because you tried to read past the end of the file, so the loop ends.

The correct way to do this is:

```
    struct clientsData client;
    while (fread(&client, 1, sizeof(struct clientsData) , fp) == sizeof(struct clientsData))
    {
        printf("%d\t%d\t%s\n",client.num1, client.num2, client.str);
    }
```

Note that this is also more efficient, as you don't call feof.

Answer (score 1):

feof() only returns true after an attempt to read past the end of file; check the return value from fread to ensure it actually returns data.